# Generate all posible combinations with repetition of given length in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, combinations, combinatorics

I need to generate all posible combinations of the given length (letters can be repeated) in JavaScript. Something that can be written in ruby using `for word in ('a'*4..'z'*4)`.

Comment: @Bergi I've tried to search for "combinations in JavaScript" on SO and try their code with some modifications but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript has no such functional syntax. With the new list comprehensions, you might possibly do such a thing, but they are not supported widely. So you will need to create the strings manually in a loop:

```
var from = 97,
    to = from + 26,
    rep = 4,
    callback = function(str) { … };
(function recurse(arr, len) {
    if (len < rep)
        for (var i=from; i<to; i++) {
            arr[len] = i;
            recurse(arr, len+1);
        }
    else
        callback( String.fromCharCode.apply(null, arr) );

})([], 0);
```